# warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’

Tags: c, warnings

when I compile my code it shows me 3 warnings:

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’ 
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’
 warning: format ‘%hhu’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘unsigned char *’
```

Here's the code:

```
typedef struct
{
int c; 
int l; 
unsigned char **matrizPixels; 
} PGM;

 void salvaPGM(PGM *img, char* saida)

 {
int i,j;

FILE *arq;

arq = fopen(saida,"w");

fprintf(arq,"P2\n");
fprintf(arq,"%d ", &img->c);
fprintf(arq,"%d ", &img->l);
fprintf(arq,"255\n");

for(i = 0; i++; i < img->l )
{
    for (j = 0; j++; j < img->c)
    {
        fprintf(arq,"%hhu ",&img->matrizPixels[i][j]);
    }
     fprintf(arq,"\n");
}

   fclose (arq);
 }
```

Comment: It means exactly what it says.  It requires an `int`, but you are passing it an `int *`.

Comment: You don't need the `&` in front of the arguments to `printf()` unless you're trying to print addresses?

Comment: Two upvotes. I guess it's Reward For Not Reading The Compiler Message Day today once again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several `printf` statements with mismatched format strings and arguments.  Those mismatches will cause your program to have undefined behaviour, so the compiler is warning you.  You need to change:

```
fprintf(arq,"%d ", &img->c);
fprintf(arq,"%d ", &img->l);
```

to:

```
fprintf(arq,"%d ", img->c);
fprintf(arq,"%d ", img->l);
```

And later on:

```
    fprintf(arq,"%hhu ",&img->matrizPixels[i][j]);
```

to:

```
    fprintf(arq,"%d ",img->matrizPixels[i][j]);
```

I removed the `hh` in the last one, since it's unnecessary.  I also changed from `%u` to `%d` to match the default argument promotion that will take place.

As an aside, it appears you have your `for` loop expressions in the wrong order.  It's a bit weird to have:

```
for(i = 0; i++; i < img->l )
```

I expect you meant that to be:

```
for(i = 0; i < img->l; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `&` as `%d` is used int

Something like this:-

```
fprintf(arq,"%d ", img->c);
fprintf(arq,"%d ", img->l);
```

and

```
 fprintf(arq,"%hhu ",img->matrizPixels[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` format string specifies an `int`, but you are providing an `int *`, a pointer to an `int`.

You need to drop the `&` in front of the variables. `&x` results in a pointer to `x`, you just want `x`.

Answer (score 0):

`img` is a pointer to the PGM structure.  The statement `img->c` dereferences the pointer and addresses the c variable within PGM.  You could also code: `(*img).c` the parens are necessary because the dereference operator `*` has a very low precedence and you want it bound to `img` so that *img is a dereferenced structure.

& is the address operator and it creates a pointer.  The statement `&img->c` produces a pointer to `c`, but printf wants `c` not a pointer to it.

Thus, write `img->c` (per other answers) or `(*img).c`